# launch cmd with parameters

Tags: php, cmd, exec, port

I do this in cmd to put 0 on port 15:

```
set / p x = "1" <nul> \ \. \ COM15
```

I would do it with php:

```
exec (cmd / c "set / p x = \" 1 \ "<nul> \ \ \ COM15.");
```

I do not know how
If anyone can help me ?
Thank you in advance
Steve...

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is really hard to understand what you are asking for. And try to show that you've made some effort in looking for an answer by yourself; your PHP sample (well I think it is one) is not even syntactically correct.

Comment: I want to send a value to the serial port from php.

Comment: I did not find anything very clear

Comment: Thank's à lot grebneke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And quoting/escaping the command properly doesn't work? Single quotes?

```
exec('set / p x = "1" <nul> \ \. \ COM15');
```